# Angular 2 with ngrx/store: how to share data between reducers?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have a simple list component in my app. And I want list items to be selectable. So my application state looks like this:

```
AppState {
    items: Array<Item>,
    selected: Array<Identifier>
}
```

And my bootstrap:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    provideStore({
        items: ItemsReducer,
        selected: SelectedReducer
    })
]);
```

List's behavior is simple. Single click - item's ID added to selected array, others are cleared. Ctrl+Click - item's ID added to selected array, others remain. It's easy to implement with current structure.

But I also want to make it possible to select a range of items with Shift+Click - in which case all items between last selected and current one should be selected as well. To do that I need to know not only the current item but also the last selected and have access to the list to find items between them. But obviously I don't have access to `items` in `SelectedReducer`.

So how can I do that? Should I maybe consider restructuring my store, so `items` and `selected` would be in one state-object? Or use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) (seems like an overkill)? Any other options?

Comment: Is the selected state used reactively for something? The question is whether the list of selected is better handled within the component, and all you are interested in is the result. It may be better to read a slice of the items in the component and dispatch the result to the selected reducer. If that doesn't suffice look at @Effects. Ngrx/effects.

Comment: Well, I have a counter of selected items. Also I would like to be able to delete all selected items, for example. And I'm planning on creating several lists with an ability to drag'n'drop items between them. Don't know if that's reactive. I'll look into ngrx/effects, thanks!

Comment: @DerekKite you should add the comment as an answer, I was writing one and it came out exactly what you suggested :) Selection should not be in the reducer, either component or a side effect.